# Need to add 1 pos. to the substring in this SQL

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

This sql is working but the second substring, is the order num. For these we need to add a '0' at the end, to make it 8 pos now. Not sure how to do this in SQL.

```
SELECT                                                             
  ALL       SUBSTR(UANOTL,1,4) AS CODE1, SUBSTR(UANOTL,5,7) AS ORDER#, 
            UAATHN, UANOTD                                                 
  FROM      ASTDTA.NOTEH1 T01                                      
  WHERE     SUBSTR(UANOTL,1,4) = 'REM '
```

Comment: so if you have 1234567, do you want it to be 01234567, or 12345670?

Comment: Will it **always** be just a _single_ zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [concatenation operator](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzwtco.htm):

```
SELECT ALL 
  SUBSTR(UANOTL,1,4) AS CODE1, 
  SUBSTR(UANOTL,5,7) || '0' AS ORDER#, 
  UAATHN, UANOTD
FROM ASTDTA.NOTEH1 T01
WHERE SUBSTR(UANOTL,1,4) = 'REM '
```

Answer (score 0):

you just put an & operator before the string and the 0 you want to add

so 0 in front would be

```
select ('0' & ORDER#)
```

and at the end would be

```
select (ORDER# & '0')
```

Comment: That seems unlikely to work in any version of DB2 though I haven't used all versions, nor perhaps in any other DBMS that maintains adherence to SQL standards. It definitely won't work for this question.